# SetMatrix has no effect (WebCamTexture Unity)

Tags: ios, matrix, unity-game-engine, shader

I'm using WebCamTexture to get input from the camera (iOS&Android). However, since this is raw input, the rotation is wrong when rendered to a texture. I read around a lot, and found this (look at the bottom): [WebCamTexture rotated and flipped on iPhone](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/webcamtexture-rotated-and-flipped-on-iphone-when-applied-to-renderer-material-texture.126702/)

His code (but with test-values):

```
Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(45f, 30f, 90f);
Matrix4x4 rotationMatrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(Vector3.zero, rotation, new Vector3(1, 1, 1));
material.SetMatrix("_Rotation", rotationMatrix);
```

But whatever value I use, nothing happens (neither in the editor or on devices)...

Thanks!

**Edit**
After some intense testing, I found that material.SetMatrix, SetFloat, SetWhatever has NO effect (not setting the value) unless it's declared inside the "Properties"-block. Looking at unity:s own example, this should't have to (and can't) be done for a matrix (can't be declared inside Properties, only inside the CGProgram). So... How do you set a matrix then? Or what else am I doing wrong?

Comment: Couple of things.  1. Rotations aren't cumulative w/ `SetMatrix` so your snippet will only rotate once at the start.  2. The shader you linked *only* rotates the geometry, not the texture (maybe you want this?).  The official docs have a [working example](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetMatrix.html) of texture rotation.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out! I should have mentioned that I touch shaders once every 3 years... :)

Comment: @Jerdak

Btw, care to explain a little more how that solution "rotates the geometry, not the texture"? TY!

Comment: The only place `_rotation` is used in that shader is this line: `float4 newPosition = mul( UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, mul(_Rotation, v.vertex) );`, that's part of the vertex shader and is applied only to vertices at `o.pos = newPosition` so it only rotates the geometry.

Comment: @Jerdak And what I really want is to calculate the texcoord..? It's late, I don't know shaders or its syntax and... yeah, sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be using: **WebCamTexture.videoRotationAngle**

its designed to solve exactly this problem, read more about this [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture-videoRotationAngle.html).

Example code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public WebCamTexture webcamTexture;
    public Quaternion baseRotation;
    void Start() {
        webcamTexture = new WebCamTexture();

        renderer.material.mainTexture = webcamTexture;
        baseRotation = transform.rotation;
        webcamTexture.Play();
   }
   void Update() {
       transform.rotation = baseRotation * Quaternion.AngleAxis(webcamTexture.videoRotationAngle, Vector3.up);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the problem is that I've integrated it with NGUI (using UITexture), thus I can not rotate the object since it's hooked up with constraints. I need to do it in shader.

Answer (score 0):

Just rotate the camera to 90 degrees along the z axis (the camera is which is rendering the `webcamtexture` gameobject).